# Windows Phone - Binding listbox to static singleton Repository of ObservableCollection of WCF service items?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, listbox, observablecollection

Is that possible? I know with ViewModel pattern, but I have Repository Pattern implemented as Singleton (I have private constructor) and inside of repository I have ObservableCollection of some item which a get from a WCF service?

My question is, how to bind that ObservableCollection to a listbox?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? Just bind it to the collection:

```
<ListBox ItemSource={Binding YourObservableCollection} />
```